# Can postfix relay or map to multiple hosts at the same time?

Tags: postfix

I would like, if possible, to have postfix relay THE SAME EXACT email to two locations at the same time(or close to same time). Not failover, but duplicates. Can this be done via relayhosts or transports and can someone help me out?

The end result is that I would have two separate exchange servers receiving mail for the same domains & users, neither one knows about the other one.

Answer (score 1):

In postfix, you would have to alter it through virtual alias expansion in order to do that.  Something like

user@domain.com: user@domain.com,user@2ndcopy.domain.com

And then set your transport maps accordingly

user@2ndcopy.domain.com relay:[1.2.3.4]

You would need to do something to rewrite the header on the 2ndcopy.domain.com exchange server.